# How to combine two tables into own this the same columns?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have two tables A and B. A has two columns: id, amount. B also has two columns: id, amount.
I hope to combine A and B to create a new table C, with same two columns:id, amount. How can I do it using SQL?
For example:

```
A
    ('A1',1)
    ('A2',5)
    ('A3',2)
    ('A4',5)
    ('A5',2)
    ('A6',7)
B
    ('A1',3)
    ('A3',2)
    ('A4',7)
    ('A5',4)
    ('A8',2)
    ('A9',10)
```

so C should be:

```
C
    ('A1',4)
    ('A2',5)
    ('A3',4)
    ('A4',12)
    ('A5',6)
    ('A6',7)
    ('A8',2)
    ('A9',10)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT  ID, SUM(Amount) total
FROM
        (
            SELECT ID, Amount FROM A
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ID, AMount FROM B
        ) s
GROUP   BY ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/941b9/5)

You can create a table base on the result from the query.

```
CREATE TABLE C
AS
SELECT  ID, SUM(Amount) total
FROM
        (
            SELECT ID, Amount FROM A
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ID, AMount FROM B
        ) s
GROUP   BY ID;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b98f3/1)

Comment: +1 You could also add CREATE TABLE c LIKE a :) though I'm not sure if Oracle has that feature.

Comment: Thank you! Another question(sorry I'm new to sql), if the A and B is just the select result, how can I implement this? I mean, A is not a real table, I use SELECT FROM WHERE get A...Do I need to create a view or something? Thank you!

Comment: @lkkeepmoving yes you can create a view but if you don't want to do it, you can also use that query in a subquery, eg `SELECT ID, Amount FROM (...add the query here...) newTB`

Comment: Got it. Last question, if I want to create C ordered by the amount descending, how can I do it?

Comment: just add order by clause, see here, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eeeff/1 there is a create table statement at the last part of the left window.

Answer (score -2):

the answer above works absolutely fine. Just to add to it an order by clause that will sort by ID.

```
SELECT  ID, SUM(Amount) as total
FROM
        (
            SELECT ID, Amount FROM A
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ID, AMount FROM B
        ) s
GROUP by ID
order by ID
```