# Best practices to store every minute and select from database latest 24h data only?

Tags: python-3.x, mariadb

The task is to permanently record new data to a database every minute and then, occasionally, to read only latest 24h data, using Python.

The only approach I know:

- create a script A that will be inserting into a MariaDB database table, one new line per minute, with a timestamp as a field value
- create a script B that will be reading from the database table, using WHERE and timestamp values

The problem is, there are 2 restrictions:

- it is not allowed to have more than 10.000 lines in one database table
- it is not allowed to delete any lines

How to fulfill the task and meet both restrictions? Are there best practices?

Thanks!

Comment: You can generate new database tables for every day. In that case you need 2 queries. One to look at the table of the current day and one for the previous day. There should only be 24 * 60 = 1140 lines written per day, which is below the 10.000 lines threshold and you don't have to delete any data. I am not aware of any best practices in this regard, but maybe someone else can enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new table every X days when it is full. Name the table with the first timestamp value.

With this solution you need to create your B script in this way:

- List all tables
- Find the tables you are looking for
- Write your SQL query on all theses tables using [UNION ALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038919/how-to-combine-two-tables-into-own-this-the-same-columns)

You can do it into a single SQL query for optimisation or into a script using multiple queries for simplicity.